# how to describe a connection string in appsetting.json?

Tags: json, sqlite, asp.net-core, url, connection-string

I am using sqllite database and I have a connection string(`//20.0.0.x/x/y/z.db`).but I couldn't define this address in json.

if I write `url="filename=//20.0.0.a/x/y/z.db"` in json, then `'x'` is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string.

if I write `url="filename=//20.0.0.a//x//y//z.db"`  in json then the SQLite says

> Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error complains about the connection string, not appsettings. Create and test a valid connection string first, *then* store it as a simple string in the `ConnectionStrings` section in `appsettings.json`. The Microsoft.Data.SQLite [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings) show the connection string should look like `Data Source=path/to/my.db`. ADO.NET doesn't use a `url` parameter

Comment: Besides, SQLite is a file-based embedded database not meant to be shared among clients. The entire database runs inside your application. You can use multiple threads if you use `Cache=Shared` and start it in WAL mode. If you really really want to save it in a shared folder, the path is the same you'd use in Windows Explorer, eg `\\myfileserver\sharedfoldername\my.db`, not `url="filename=//20.0.0.a/x/y/z.db"`. ADO.NET doesn't use a `url` parameter

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion like :

In Program.cs,add code like below:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourDbContext")));
```

In appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "YourDbContext": "Filename= C:\\Users\\Administrator\\sqlite\\ITProjectDB.db"   // use your db path
  }
```